# Is there a way to read network response status codes from the Browser in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, http

I am making a function call using a private node package that calls an API. This package however does not return a response when the function that makes the API request is called. Thus there is no way of verifying if the HTTP request was successful unless you check the Network tab in the browser's developer tools for the response code.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea on how to read these status codes in my situation, I found a useful package but it is in React Native, please see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-logger

Any ideas or package recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't call a "package" in JavaScript, I think you mean `function`.

Comment: @Dai My bad, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I hope the edit helps!

Comment: You can use `PerformanceObserver` to inspect and record Network activity and requests (from both `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver - but this is a bit of a hack - can't you make your own client library for the remote web-service? Or generate it with Swagger?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the recommendation, I will look into PerformanceObserver. Unfortunately, I am unable to make my own client library or alter the package as it is above my permissions, all I can do is try to figure something out that works with the package given to me, personally I'd definitely include a response from the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the response status code in HEADERS
[image]